# Robots.txt in Magento Websites

Tags: magento, robots.txt

I have recently started working with a company that has a Magento eCommerce website.

We spotted that the traffic dipped considerably in May, and also the ranking on Google.

When I started investigating i saw that the pages of the ES website were not appearing on Screaming Frog

Only the homepage showed and status said blocked by robots.txt

I said this to my developer and they  said they would move the robot.txt file to the /pub folder.

but would that not mean the file was in two places.. would this be an issue?

The developer has gone ahead and done this, how long should it take to see is screaming frog is indexing the pages.

Any Magento developers that could help with advise on this?

Thanks

Neo

Answer (score 0):

There is a [documentation page](https://support.hypernode.com/en/ecommerce/magento-2/how-to-create-a-robots-txt-for-magento-2-x) for how to manage robots.txt with `Magento 2.x`.

And you can use this to allow all traffic to your site:

```
User-agent:*
Disallow:
```

Regarding the Googlebot crawl rate, here is some [explanation](https://www.boostability.com/how-often-is-google-crawling-my-site/) on it.

> According to Google, “crawling and indexing are processes which can take some time and which rely on many factors.” It’s estimated that it takes anywhere between a few days to four weeks before Googlebots index a new site. If you have an older website and doesn’t experience crawling, the design of the site may be a problem. Sometimes, sites are temporarily unavailable when Google attempted to crawl, so checking the crawl stats and looking at errors can help you make changes to get your site crawled. Google also has two different crawlbots: a desktop crawler to simulate a user on a desktop, and a mobile crawler to simulate a device search.

Comment: Thanks @chenrui ,  I think that the issue was that the pages had not been added to the /public folder. When we did this we jumped from page 2 to page 1 for some of our top keyword searches..